# Text disappeared from buttons

Tags: css

I am trying to have it so users can log in into my website using fb etc. For some reason, the text gets hidden behind the buttons in my existing code. I am not sure what's wrong since the text used to show up where it needed to be up until I changed the background of the buttons and added social icons to them. Could you please help?

Here is the relevant code:
HTML:

```
    <a class="alt-sign-in facebook">Login with facebook</a>
    <a class="alt-sign-in google">Login with google</a>
    <a class="alt-sign-in twitter">Login with twitter</a>


    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
    <button id="computer-button">Start</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    @import url('http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo');
 @import url('http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=zocial');
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
}
.alt-sign-in {
    position: relative;
    display:block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px 0px auto auto;
    padding: 5px;
    font: 700 16px/40px'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: #555;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 40%, lightgrey);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.alt-sign-in:before {
    color:white;
    position:relative;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    display:block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45px;
    font: 20px/40px entypo;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prettysweet/Dv9rC/24/

Thank you so much!

Comment: In case one of the answers has helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted seems to be an incomplete, or older version.

But by judging from your jsfiddle link, I suggest to change the following;

```
.alt-sign-in {
    /* removed: box-sizing: border-box; */
}

.alt-sign-in:before {
    position:absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/Dv9rC/27/

Comment: `left` and `top` should be set to `0px`

Comment: @nejo I haven't browsertested this, but on latest mac firefox it looks better with `left:5px; top:5px` http://imgur.com/PoG2Rg3

Comment: @nejo I see now, I edited my answer to remove the unneeded box-sizing property so it looks the same across ff & chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have floating element problem. If you add these lines to your css code, it'll be OK.

```
.alt-sign-in.facebook:before {
...
float: left;
}

.alt-sign-in.google:before {
...
float: left;
}

.alt-sign-in.twitter:before {
...
float: left;
}
```

Bonus Edit: After adding all of these codes, just add form tag to your CSS document for top margin.

```
form{
 margin-top:15px;   
}
```